# ¿Cómo hago para que salga el nombre de quien inicio sesión?

Tags: php

Sólo me sale el `email` o el `rol` pero pongo el `name` y no me sale ni error ni nada, solo no sale el nombre de usuario.

La consulta la tengo de esta manera:

Tengo este login que al ingresar muestra el nombre en la barra de navegación. El problema es que no me muestra el nombre del usuario con que ingresas sino que no está mostrando el nombre:

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once 'conexion.php';
$objeto = new Conexion();
$conexion = $objeto->Conectar();


$email = (isset($_POST['email'])) ? $_POST['email'] : '';
$password = (isset($_POST['password'])) ? $_POST['password'] : '';
$pass = md5($password);

$consulta = "SELECT users.level AS level, users.name AS name, rols.rol AS rol  FROM users JOIN rols ON users.level = rols.id WHERE  email='$email' AND password='$pass' ";
$resultado = $conexion->prepare($consulta);
$resultado->execute();


if ($resultado->rowCount() >= 1) {
    $data = $resultado->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $_SESSION["email"] = $email;
    $_SESSION["name"] = $data["name"];
    $_SESSION["level"] = $data[0]["level"];
    $_SESSION["rol_rol"] = $data[0]["rol"];
} else { 
    $_SESSION["level"] = null;
    $data = null;
}

print json_encode($data);
$conexion = null;
```

¿Qué podría hacer?, soy principiante en esto, me gustaría que me pudieran ayudar.

Es decir, por ejemplo: `BIENVENIDO(A) jesus`.

He realizado varias consultas y nada, no se que podría estar haciendo mal.

Comment: En vez de `$data["name"]` prueba con `$data[0]["name"]`

Comment: gracias!!! si funciono

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El metodo `fetchAll()` te devuelve un array asociativo, por la cual debes ingresar a la posición del array que te devuelve, con `[0]` (tal como haces con los demás datos):

```
if ($resultado->rowCount() >= 1) {
    $data = $resultado->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $_SESSION["email"] = $email;
    $_SESSION["name"] = $data[0]["name"];
    $_SESSION["level"] = $data[0]["level"];
    $_SESSION["rol_rol"] = $data[0]["rol"];
}
```

Y para comprobar el resultado, puedes hacer un `echo` al final del `if`:

```
if ($resultado->rowCount() >= 1) {
    $data = $resultado->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $_SESSION["email"] = $email;
    $_SESSION["name"] = $data[0]["name"];
    $_SESSION["level"] = $data[0]["level"];
    $_SESSION["rol_rol"] = $data[0]["rol"];
    echo "Bienvenido(a) " . $_SESSION["name"];
}
```

Comment: gracias me funciono perfecto !! muy amable

Comment: Me alegro que le haya funcionado, saludos!